# How to rewrite rules for one page only with GET parameters using .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to URL rewriting.

**What I have done so far:**

Using several online resources I am successfully able  to rewrite my URL `loclahost/mysite/attach.php?q=1` to `localhost/mysite/attach/1` through the following rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^attach/([^/]+)$ attach.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Problem:**
My problem is that using this rule all my URLs are getting overridden. If I click any link on navigation menu, it appends `attach/` before the page. Furthermore, CSS and image links are also getting overridden like this `localhost/mysite/attach/style/css/style.css` whereas it is supposed to be `localhost/mysite/style/css/style.css` hence, the browser doesn't style the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your last 3 lines to this rule and you will be all set.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=1($|&)
RewriteRule ^mysite/attach\.php$ /mysite/attach/1?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: No luck. It got even worse. It gives me 404 Error. Object not found.